# A way to get averages over a period of days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with five years worth of data.  It has, among other values, `JulianDate`, `RefETo`, and `Precipitation`.

I need to get the average of RefETo over that five years and the average of the last year, plus the sum of precipitation over the last year.

At the same time the averages and sums have to be for a period of time between 7 and 28 days.

Right now, I'm doing it with a function:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[CIMISAvg](@Stn INT, @Yr INT,  @Period INT)
RETURNS @AvgTable TABLE (Period INT, RefETo float, RefETo1 float, Precipitation float)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PeriodInc INT = 1
    DECLARE @RefETo float
    DECLARE @Precip float
    DECLARE @RefETo1 float
    DECLARE @P INT = 1
    BEGIN
        WHILE @PeriodInc < 366
           BEGIN
              IF @PeriodInc < 365
                 BEGIN
                    SET @RefETo = (SELECT AVG(RefETo) FROM Cimis 
                     WHERE StationNo = @Stn AND RefETO >= 0 AND JulianDate BETWEEN @PeriodINC AND 
                     PeriodINC + @Period - 1)
                    SET @RefETo1 = (SELECT AVG(RefETo) FROM Cimis WHERE StationNo = @Stn AND 
                     RefETO >= 0 AND JulianDate BETWEEN @PeriodINC AND @PeriodINC + @Period - 1 
                     AND DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr)
                    SET @Precip = (SELECT SUM(Precipitation) FROM Cimis 
                     WHERE StationNo = @Stn AND Precipitation >= 0 AND JulianDate 
                     BETWEEN @PeriodINC AND @PeriodINC + @Period - 1 
                     AND DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr)
                 END
              ELSE
                 BEGIN
                    SET @RefETo = (SELECT AVG(RefETo) FROM Cimis 
                     WHERE StationNo = @Stn AND RefETO >= 0 
                     AND (JulianDate > 364 OR JulianDate < @Period - 1))                        
                    SET @RefETo1 = (SELECT AVG(RefETo) FROM Cimis WHERE StationNo = @Stn 
                     AND RefETO >= 0  AND JulianDate > 364 
                     AND DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr)
                    SET @Precip = (SELECT SUM(Precipitation) FROM Cimis WHERE StationNo = @Stn 
                     AND Precipitation >= 0 AND JulianDate > 364 
                     AND DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr)
                 END
              INSERT INTO @AvgTable(Period, RefETo, RefETo1, Precipitation) 
              VALUES (@P, @RefETo, @RefETo1, @Precip)
              SET @PeriodInc += @Period
              SET @P += 1
           END
        END
   RETURN
END
```

It returns the following table if I use:

```
SELECT * from dbo.CimiAvg(80,2014,28)
```

```
Period RefETo                RefETo1               Precipitation
1      0.0417192857142857    0.0470392857142857    0.0156
2      0.0672328571428571    0.0585214285714286    0
3      0.121372142857143     0.135967857142857     1.2755
4      0.170277519379845     0.186428571428571     0.7991
5      0.235207258064516     0.240425              0.7087
6      0.268260240963855     0.294403571428571     0.1811
7      0.293128125           0.290282142857143     0
8      0.273767123287671     0.267457142857143     0.0196
9      0.244358333333333     0.2513375             0
10     0.176087142857143     NULL                  NULL
11     0.10749               NULL                  NULL
12     0.0625579831932773    NULL                  NULL
13     0.0382158273381295    NULL                  NULL
14     0.0413401459854015    NULL                  NULL
```

Which is fine and dandy but does anyone have any better ideas?

I've fiddled around with

```
SELECT JulianDate, AVG(RefETO) 
                   OVER (ORDER BY JulianDate ROWS BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
FROM Cimis
```

and variations on that but haven't got anywhere

Comment: I hope I never have to maintain that system!

Comment: sample data? expected result (from that data)? reading your function is ok, but it would be much more fun to have data to work with, and more likely to produce you a worthwhile result

Comment: You can implement ranges with `CASW WHEN ... END` clauses inside your aggregate functions in a single SQL statement. I saw this method being referred to as *conditional aggregation*.

Comment: I tweaked the code to remove the test for negative RefETo and Precipitation.  Perhaps using COUNT(*) for RefEToDays handles leap year?  If not let me know the issue, and we'll fix.

Comment: I think I have it all sorted out.  I put the final code in my previous post.  I'm testing this on SQL Server 2014 Express and for some reason, it doesn't like ROUNDUP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [PM 77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1) in the comments. Conditional aggregation is the way to go.

Try this:

```
Declare @Stn INT, @Yr INT,  @Period INT
Select @Stn = 80, @Yr=2014, @Period=28

SELECT Period, RefETo/RefEToDays AS RefETo, RefETo1/RefETo1Days AS RefETo1, Precipitation
FROM    (
    SELECT 
    ROUNDUP(JulianDate/@Period,0) AS Period,
    SUM(
      RefETo
    ) AS RefETo,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr  THEN RefETo ELSE 0 END
    ) AS RefETo1,
    COUNT(*)
      AS RefEToDays,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS RefETo1Days,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr Then Precipitation ELSE 0 END
    ) AS Precipitation
    FROM Cimis
    WHERE StationNo = @Stn 
    GROUP BY ROUNDUP(JulianDate/@Period,0)
    ) c
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the average of RefETo over that five years and the
>   average of the last year, plus the sum of precipitation over the last
>   year.

From where I sit, this is a perfect example of a requirement that should be implemented in the report writer, not in the dbms.

I would not do this in a single SQL statement.

Comment: That's absurd - you are suggesting sending the entire dataset down to the client to perform aggregations? That's what RDBMS's do for breakfast.

Comment: No, report writers can do these three different aggregations on the server. I'm saying it doesn't makes sense to mix rows that represent average RefTo over a five-year period with rows that represent the sum of precipitation over a single year.

Comment: Perhaps you can see why it is impossible for my answer to work then.

Comment: "It doesn't make sense" and "It's impossible" are two different things. I said only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There definitely is a better, and more perforrmant, means to this end.

First be sure you either have a [NUMBERS table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) defined in your database, or are familiar with how to generate one dynamically using a CTE (Common Table Expression):

The main query now becomes:

```
DECLARE @NumPeriods as INT = 365 / @Period;

WITH
    -- vvv BEGIN Needed only in absence of a NUMBERS table
    E1(N) as (
        SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES  (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)  )E1(N)
    ),
    E2(N) as ( SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b ),
    E4(N) as ( SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b ),
      -- repeated for E8, E16, as needed
    -- ^^^ END Needed only in absence of a NUMBERS table

Tally(N) as (
    SELECT TOP(@NumPeriods) -- This is sufficient for our purposes 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS N 
    FROM E4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0
)
INSERT INTO @AvgTable(Period, RefETo, RefETo1, Precipitation) 
    SELECT
         p.Period
        ,AVG(RefETo) as RefETo
        ,SUM(case when DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @yr then RefETo else 0 end)
        /SUM(case when DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @yr then    1   else 0 end) 
                     as RefETo1
        ,SUM(case when DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @yr then Precipitation 
                                                           else 0 end)
                     as Precipitation
    FROM Cimis
    JOIN (
        SELECT
             N, N + 1           as Period
            ,(N*@Period) + 1 as StartDate
            ,CASE WHEN N * @Period > 363 THEN @Period - 1 ELSE (N + 1) * @Period END AS EndDate

        FROM Tally
    ) p
       ON JulianDate BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate 
       OR ((JulianDate > 364 OR JulianDate < @Period - 1) AND p.N * @Period > 363)

    WHERE StationNo  = @Stn
      AND RefETO    >= 0 
    GROUP BY  p.Period
    PRDER BY  p.Period
```

I believe you will find this implementation to be vastly faster on large data sets than your current implementation.

Comment: Indeed, that does work much faster; however, the last period doesn't work.  For instance, for a period of 28 days, the last interval would be Julian days 365, 366, and Julian days 1 - 26.  So, I need to figure a way to add that in there but thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

This I think is the final version based on Jim V's code.   The last period is handled with a UNION.

```
DECLARE @Stn INT, @Yr INT,  @Period INT
SELECT @Stn = 80, @Yr=2014, @Period=28

SELECT Period, RefETo, RefETo1, Precipitation
FROM (
SELECT CEILING(JulianDate / @Period) AS Period, AVG(RefETo) AS RefETo, 
AVG(CASE WHEN DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr THEN RefETo ELSE NULL END) AS RefETo1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr Then Precipitation ELSE 0 END) AS
Precipitation 
FROM Cimis WHERE StationNo = @Stn AND JulianDate < 365
GROUP BY CEILING(JulianDate / @Period)) C
UNION SELECT 366 / @Period + 1 AS Period, AVG(RefETo) AS RefETo, 
(SELECT AVG(RefETo) FROM CIMIS 
WHERE DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr AND JulianDate > 364) AS RefETo1,
(SELECT SUM(Precipitation) FROM CIMIS 
WHERE DATEPART(Year, DateCollected) = @Yr AND JulianDate > 364) AS Precipitation 
FROM Cimis WHERE StationNo = @Stn AND (JulianDate > 364 OR JulianDate < @Period - 1) 
ORDER BY Period
```

Comment: On even further review, the code by Jim V with some modification is the way to go.